# Office JS / Excel JS: How do I create a copy of my add-in's current workbook?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am building an Excel Add-in and would like to create a new workbook that is a copy of the currently open workbook.

I am able to create an empty workbook using `Excel.createWorkbook()`, I am able to read the currently open file as **plaintext** using `Office.context.document.getFileAsync()`, and I am even able to create a duplicate of an existing file using `Excel.createWorkbook(base64)` where `base64` is the output of an online converter like [this one](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file).

However, I am unable to connect these pieces together. In particular, I've found that `Office.context.document.getFileAsync()` and its documentation don't clearly explain how to get the necessary `base64` format of the file. As I said, I can load the file as plaintext or a byte array, but not `base64`. I believe that once I can figure this part out, I can use the `base64` to create a duplicate of the currently open file.

In the docs, there is a [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook) about creating a copy of an existing workbook. The docs go on to say that:

> You can get your add-in's current workbook as a base64-encoded string by using [file slicing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=common-js-preview#office-office-document-getfileasync-member(1)).

The docs claim that we can get the current workbook as a base64-encoded string, but the function mentioned requires a `FileType` which only has 3 options: Text, Compressed Byte Array, and PDF. None of these are base64 encoded. Do I have to manually convert these myself? The documentation is a bit lacking in this area.